# Event after Layout action of Control Performed

Tags: c#, winforms

In Winforms, My control contain child controls. Insailly size of parent control(in load event) is less but after display it expand on the basis of child controls but inn code i need origanal size of parent control. Is any event after all the Layouting performed or any other approch ?

I also try PerformLayout() but it does not work.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you store the initial size of your parent control before the InitializeComponent(); function inside the constructor?

Comment: size parent depends upon your machine resolution, cannot get untill control loaded.